# Start and Stop java process from JAR Fil

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, runtime.exec

I am working on a multi-platform GUI for a project. The GUI needs to have the functionality to start and stop the other .jar file using buttons.

The GUI is coded in Java and compiled as an executable Jar file.

For example.

When the JButton start is pressed the file project_release.jar is launched.

When the JButton stop is pressed the project_release.jar file terminates and closes.

How can this be achieved so it works on all operating systems?

I've looked at process builder, Runtime and stuff but I'm not sure if it will work on multiple OS's.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime.getRuntime().exec() or ProcessBuilder() should both work fine for this, although you'll need know where the java executable is on your platform. If the java executable is in [PATH](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) then this will work cross-platform:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar project_release.jar");
```

To kill it you could use a socket connection between the programs and send a message that the other should terminate. If something goes wrong and the other program ignores the message, you can use this:

```
proc.destroy();
```

but it may interrupt the other program in the middle of something important.

Comment: how would that work for it being in two different buttons because I can't make the `Process = null;` and then use it in a try catch situation for button 1 to start the program and then again use proc.destroy(); to end the program.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Have you tried it? What particular part are you having trouble with?